# Approve that $f = \frac{x}{1 - x^2}$ is an injective function

Tags: calculus

Assume that $f: R \setminus  \{-1,1\} \to R$ and $f = \frac{x}{1-x^2}$. Approve that $f$ is an injective function.

*My solution:*

Based on the theory: for each $x,y \in R \setminus \{-1,1 \} $ if $ f(x) = f(y) $ then $x=y$

$ x - xy^2 = y -yx^2 \Leftrightarrow x - y = xy^2 - x^2y \Leftrightarrow x-y = xy(y^2 - x^2) \Leftrightarrow x-y = xy(y-x)(y+x) \Leftrightarrow (y-x)[xy(y+x) +1 ) = 0$

Two cases:

1) $x = y$

or

2) $(xy(y+x) +1 ) = 0$

**Edit:**

---

$ x - xy^2 = y -yx^2 \Leftrightarrow x - y = xy^2 - x^2y \Leftrightarrow x-y = xy(y - x) $

Two cases:

1) $x = y$

or

2) $xy = -1$

---

We reject the second. So, f is injective function

*My question:*

1) Can we reject the second case? Please explain!

**Answer of the Community**

No, we can not reject the second case !

Comment: $xy^2-x^2y = xy(y-x)$ no squares on the right hand side...

Comment: Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the very definition, as you did:

$$f(x)=f(y)\iff\frac x{1-x^2}=\frac y{1-y^2}\iff x-xy^2=y-x^2y\iff $$

$$\iff(x-y)=-xy(x-y)\iff\begin{cases}x=y\\or\\xy=-1\end{cases}$$

Thus, any pair of numbers $\;x,\,y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{-1,1\}\;$ s.t. $\;xy=-1\;$ give you a counterexample to injectivity. For example

$$x=-2,\,y=\frac12\;,\;\text{and certainly:}\;\;f(-2)=\frac{-2}{1-4}=\frac23=\frac{\frac12}{1-\frac14} =f\left(\frac12\right)$$

and etc.

Answer (score 3):

It is not an injective function as we can see from horizontal line test.

[image]

Comment: It equals for $x,y$ such that $x\cdot y = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your computation:

$$ x - y = xy^2 - x^2y \iff x-y = xy\color{red}{(y - x)}\iff\begin{cases}x=y \\ xy=-1\iff y=-\frac1x, \; x\ne 0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I edited. Thank you

Comment: You can not say that $y= \frac{1}{x}$ because $x$ can be $0$